# Regional Setting Decimal Separator

Tags: c#

I have written a program intended only for users in the US and UK. However, one of my client install the Windows 7 Enterprise and Spanish Language OS. So my program uses comma as the decimal separator instead of decimal point, therefore my program get screwed up!

I try to fix it for him by changing back the regional setting in his machine to English (UK), however it's still not working! The program still use the comma as the decimal point!

How should I fix it?

Comment: Although Jeroen suggest a workaround - it's strage that you bother about separator character unless you parse numbers manually. Use standard .net localization/globalization approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can set your Culture when bootstrapping your application:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

This is for the UI, before the init component

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```